# foreach loop output first value only in loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array, array-unique

Why foreach loop printing only the first value from the array?

```
$Jdata_cate = '[{"category_id":"103","name":"Martin","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"10","name":"Juan","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"9","name":"Kasi","parent_id":0}]';
    $J_Min = strtolower($Jdata_cate);
    $J_MinDecoded = json_decode($J_Min, true);

    $Ddata_cate = '[{"category_id":"55","name":"Abc","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"41","name":"Pedro","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"40","name":"Kasi","parent_id":0}]';
    $D_Min = strtolower($Ddata_cate);
    $D_MinDecoded = json_decode($D_Min, true);

    $both_arrays = array_merge((array)$J_MinDecoded, (array)$D_MinDecoded);

    $Delete_repeated = array_unique($both_arrays);

    foreach($Delete_repeated as $y=>$y_value){
            echo $y_value['name'] . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: You've not provided enough information for us to go on. Can you share the arrays?

Comment: Yes of course @JayBlanchard, let me a moment to modify the question

Comment: Make sure you add a `print_r($Delete_repeated)` that may well tell you what is wrong with the previous statements

Comment: Foreach loop will iterate basis on your total index present inside an array.If the array consist of single index then it will print single time.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Now i have added the arrays. If i add `print_r($Delete_repeated);` also prints the first value of the array. I supose that the problem it is, this part of the code `$both_arrays = array_merge((array)$J_MinDecoded, (array)$D_MinDecoded);` The problem it is that i need to mix the two arrays to know which data it its repeated. How i can fix it?

Comment: @Metoballaes ok the major question is: what is the unique array, I mean is the all elements of the array must be the same or only `name` or `category_id`? are `{"category_id":"9","name":"Kasi","parent_id":0}` and `{"category_id":"40","name":"Kasi","parent_id":0}` supposed to be considered as the same?

Comment: Only the name @Zeusarm, How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution:

```
function array_unique_multidimensional($array, $key)
{
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}

$Jdata_cate = '[{"category_id":"103","name":"Martin","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"10","name":"Juan","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"9","name":"Kasi","parent_id":0}]';
$J_Min = strtolower($Jdata_cate);
$J_MinDecoded = json_decode($J_Min, true);

$Ddata_cate = '[{"category_id":"55","name":"Abc","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"41","name":"Pedro","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"40","name":"Kasi","parent_id":0}]';
$D_Min = strtolower($Ddata_cate);
$D_MinDecoded = json_decode($D_Min, true);

$both_arrays = array_merge((array)$J_MinDecoded, (array)$D_MinDecoded);

$Delete_repeated = array_unique_multidimensional($both_arrays, 'name');

foreach ($Delete_repeated as $y => $y_value) {
    echo $y_value['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

here instead of `array_unique` I'm using my defined function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you call `array_unique($both_arrays)` the default behavior is to compare items as strings, but they are arrays so it fails.

The solution is to add the `SORT_REGULAR` flag as the second parameter.

```
$Delete_repeated = array_unique($both_arrays, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now the code it working. As it is working, i noticed that the word Kasi it is not deleted because the category_id are differents. How can i deleted the word repeated Kasi in this case, if the category_id it is different.